# MSCRM Dateformatting

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

Any chance this is not the correct way to go **back 6 Months**?

```
=Format(DateAdd("M", -6, Parameters!dateIntervalEnd.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

**Parameters!dateIntervalEnd** contains a **date** entered by the user.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql the syntax of the `DateAdd` function should be `DateAdd(month, -6, Parameters!dateIntervalEnd.Value)`.

Comment: `DateAdd` isn't wrong. *Format* is. Why don't you set the culture or format property of the textbox, label, whatever you use?